# Cookie is not set in browser (Node.js + Express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies, https

I have a web server that sets a `httpOnly` cookie on the `res` object but it is not saved in the browser.

```
const refreshToken = 'my-token'
res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'none' })
```

This server is served on `https://192.168.1.179:3001`
The client application (Angular 11) is served on  `https://192.168.1.179:4200`

I generated self-signed ssl certificates for both the server and the client (And installed them as `Trusted root authorities`), don't know if that matters.

The funny thing is that the browser receives this cookie:
[image]

EDIT: I also `app.use(cors())` if that matters

Answer (score 0):

httpOnly cookies cannot be accessed by client-side application in the browser. Change httpOnly to false.

Comment: I don't need to access it in javascript. I just need it to be stored in the browser and sent on each request. The picture i sent shows that the cookie was received, but when I open devtools -> application -> cookies, The cookie is not there

Comment: I understand. When you send the cookie back to the server with request made by Angular, do you se Axios? Normally, you set `withCredentials: true` and in the server you use cors like this: `app.use(cors({credentials: true}))`.

Comment: Yes I have these options. I noticed that when I serve my app from my server (from the same domain) the cookie is saved. I guess it is just limitations about third party cookies sent over not secure connection